# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_sre.SRE_Match' and '_sre.SRE_Match'

Tags: python

I have this code, but i can't understand why i get this error:

```
a= name+pw+salt
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_sre.SRE_Match' and '_sre.SRE_Match'
```

script

```
class MainHandler(Handler):

    def make_salt(self):
        return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(5))

    def make_pw_hash(self, name, pw):
        salt = self.make_salt()    
        a= name+pw+salt //problem here

        h = hashlib.sha256(a.encode("UTF8")).hexdigest()
        return '%s|%s' % (h, salt)


    def post(self):
        store_hash_and_salt = self.make_pw_hash("José", "somePass")  
        print (store_hash_and_salt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is *not* there. Somewhere earlier you passed it the RE match results instead of using the `group()` method to obtain the strings from them.

(Also, the format of the returned string is incorrect, but that's not the bug here.)

Comment: he is right. somewhere you imported re and initialized objects and called make_pw_hash